# Can we get any performance gain from creating index from date column?

Tags: index, date

I have seen lot of indexes created on the `date` columns in my project. Normally the index is a combination of a `date` column and another column (like `state`) which are used to create an index.

Since the `date` column is the only value that gets increased, is there any performance gain from creating an index on the column?

My understanding is that the database engine creates a binary search tree as the index. I can't understand that an ever increasing value will benefit anything from a btree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone book contains a list of persons and their phone numbers.

If this list is unordered and you looking for person that isn't listed in the book, then you have to proceed each and every record in the list until the list will be exhausted.

Ordering allows us the bigger/lesser comparison. If the list is ordered and we proceed it row by row we'll find the requested row OR we'll find the row with key bigger than requested. And we can do the reasonable assumption that all the following rows have the key bigger too.

We can use the tree search on the ordered lists. Say we split the phonebook in two equal parts and look at arbitrary row in the middle. If the key is bigger than given one, we take the first half of the book and repeat the procedure recursively. If the list is unordered the tree search is impossible.

BTree splits the list in more than two parts but the idea is the same. Ordering, splitting and comparisons. That's how it goes.